# Angular material svg icons displaying the same icon for all entities

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have registered svg icons to my angular material project. but for all the icons it displays the first icon I registered. Here is my code.

```js
constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('dashboard', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/images/icons/home.svg'));
  iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('bill', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/images/icons/bill.svg'));
  iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('ticket', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/images/icons/ticket.svg'));
}
```

```js
prepareNavItems(): void {
  this.navItems = [];
  let roles: string[] = this.keycloakService.getUserRoles();
  this.navItems.push({
    name: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'dashboard',
    route: 'dashboard',
  });
  if (roles.includes("billing")) {
    this.navItems.push({
      name: 'Billing',
      icon: 'bill',
      route: 'billing',
    });
  }
  if (roles.includes("ticketing")) {
    this.navItems.push({
      name: 'Ticketing',
      icon: 'ticket',
      route: 'ticketing',
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<a *ngFor="let navItem of navItems" mat-list-item [routerLink]="[navItem.route]" routerLinkActive="mat-list-item-focus">
  <mat-icon svgIcon="{{navItem.icon}}"></mat-icon> {{navItem.name}}
</a>
```

When I run the code it displays 'dashboard' icon for all the items in the array like this.
[Chek the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM1ij.png)

What I missed ?

SOLVED:  Issue was with the svg image id. image id was same for all the svgs. by changing them to unique ids solved the issue.

Comment: This is a bug with Angular Material. There's already an issue on their Github for this but it doesn't look like they're paying any attention to it, so who knows when it'll be fixed. I had to go back to using Material icons.

Comment: Issue fixed. Issue was with the SVG image ids. it works perfectly when adding a unique id to every svg.