# svg mat-icon doesn't render correctely

Tags: html, css, angular-material, angular10, mat-icon

I have a simple `div` where i display three different icons that have different colors.

Acctualy icons are displayed, but it shows all the time the same icons either `attention-warning` or `attention-error` icon, knowing that the html code contains different icons depending on the condition.

Here i have an example where the second icon should be an attention-warning icon (yellow) but it display an attention-error icon (red) instead.

I have tested my code in both browsers, `Chrome` and `Edge` and i get same result (all red or all yellow).

Bellow code generated.

Any help please to fix this problem.

Here is my code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7anvv3?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

[image]

[image]

The icons should be in this color

[image]

Comment: it's an Angular material bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912612/angular-material-svg-icons-displaying-the-same-icon-for-all-entities

Comment: @Hamza thanks for your replay, changing an id in svg fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from my SVG, they have same ids
after changing those ids the icons displayed perfectely as expected.

Before:
[image]

After :

[image: ![enter image description here]